# Dynamically build tensor from 1s and 0s in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Given an integer tensor like `x = [2 0 1 0]` and a constant `C = 3` I would like to build a tensor

```
[[1 1 0],
 [0 0 0],
 [1 0 0],
 [0 0 0]]
```

So `C` is the number of columns, `len(x)` is the number of rows. Each entry of `x` specifies a number of 1s that a row should start with, while the remainder of that row is to be filled up with 0s.

The best TensorFlow code that I've come up with is this:

```
x = tf.constant([2, 0, 1, 0])
C = 3
r = tf.map_fn(fn=lambda i: tf.concat([tf.ones(i, dtype=tf.int32),
                                      tf.zeros(C-i, dtype=tf.int32)], 
                                     axis=0), 
              elems=x)
```

This works OK:

```
In [6]: print(r)
tf.Tensor(
[[1 1 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 0 0]], shape=(4, 3), dtype=int32)
```

But is there a straightforward way to achieve the same result without `tf.map_fn()` or any loops, but with vectorized ops like `tf.scatter_nd()` or similar?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sequence_mask (pay special attention to the `dtype` argument)

Comment: Thanks, that's a perfect fit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.sequence_mask()` produces the desired result:

```
In [8]: s = tf.sequence_mask(x, maxlen=C, dtype=tf.int32)

In [9]: print(s)
tf.Tensor(
[[1 1 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 0 0]], shape=(4, 3), dtype=int32)
```